# First character of inline cell is partially cut off

Tags: bugs, front-end, cells, rendering, inline

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0** [CASE:4900891]

---

Notice how the "f" is partially cutoff in the following inline cell.

[image: Text]

Here is the textual form.

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[TextData[{
     "This is some text. Consider the function ",
     Cell[BoxData[
        FormBox[
          RowBox[{
             RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", 
             SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], TraditionalForm]],
       FormatType -> TraditionalForm],
     "."
    }], "Text", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]
```

I can manually add a space in front of the "f" as a hack-ish fix. But is there a better way?

(I'm currently on MMA 13.0 for Mac OS (Apple Silicon) w/ MB Pro 16" macOS Monterey 12.2. But the same thing was happening on MMA 12.3 with the same machine.)

Comment: It is cut off in version 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75na.png). In version 12.3.1 on the same machine it is OK on 100% Magnification, but with Magnification 125% it is also partially cut off: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VOy.png). Hence it strongly depends on the Magnification setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce the issue with version 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75na.png)). With version 12.3.1 on the same machine it looks OK on 100% `Magnification`, but with `Magnification` 125% it is also partially cut off: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VOy.png). Hence it strongly depends on the `Magnification` setting. With version 8.0.4 installed on the same machine, the problem doesn't reproduce independently on the `Magnification`.

The simplest workaround is to not use inline cells:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"This is some text. Consider the function ", 
     FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], 
      TraditionalForm], "."}]], "Text", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is worth to point out that the size of the text in the `FromBox` is determined incorrectly:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"This is some text. Consider the function ", 
     FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], 
      TraditionalForm, BaseStyle -> {Background -> Yellow}], "."}]], "Text", 
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]
```

[image: screesnhot]

Apparently this is the reason why the first character is cut off in the inline cell.

Since incorrect determination of the sizes of textual elements is a well-known "unsolvable" problem of *Mathematica*, I think the default behavior for cell rendering should be do not cut off textual elements going beyond the cell. Currently they are cut off not only for inline, but also for ordinary cells:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
  BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], 
    TraditionalForm]], "Text", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is interesting that version 8.0.4 installed on the same machine has no such problem independently on the `Magnification`:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[
   FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", 
      SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], TraditionalForm]], "Text", 
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Magnification -> 3]]
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screesnhot]

I think current behavior should be considered as a regression bug in rendering of `Cell`s (both inline and ordinary). Reported it to the support as [CASE:4900891]. Here is the response:

> Thank you for taking the time to send your report.
>
> It does appear that CellPrint is not behaving properly. I have
> forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you
> provided, and added your contact information to the report so that you
> can be notified when it is resolved.

As one can see from the response, the subject-matter expertise of the support engineer isn't good in this case (it is not `CellPrint`, but FrontEnd's rendering of `Cell` is not proper). But it is good that the issue is registered.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response and follow-up.

Comment: @bmclaurin I updated the answer with the response from the support.

Comment: Thank you, hoping they fix this in a future update.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not fixed in 13.01, which was released a few days ago.

Comment: @bmclaurin You can report it too: the more times a bug is reported, the higher priority is assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

Does not appear to be cut off in version 12.3 on windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently on MMA 13.0 for Mac OS (Apple Silicon) w/ MB Pro 16" macOS Monterey 12.2. But the same thing was happening on MMA 12.3 with the same machine. Can anybody else on MacOS check this? Thanks.

Comment: I think this post should be converted into a comment since it doesn't provide an answer to the original question.

Comment: I agree, but posting an answerer was the only way I knew of to include an image.  How does one include a link to an image in a comment?

Comment: You can use the standard markdown for making a hyperlink: `[Google](https://www.google.com/)`.

Comment: If you need to upload an image, the simplest way is to press the "edit" button under the question and insert (upload) the image there, then copy the created URL from the code of the post (at the bottom). Then cancel the edit.

Comment: Ahh neat trick, thanks!